# How to delete line from php file as well as the newline that goes with it?

Tags: php, file, newline, whitespace, trim

I want to delete the line from a file that contains the string `$snum`. I got it to work, but it leaves a newline behind. How can I get rid of it? I tried the trim function below but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

$snum=$_GET['snum'];

$filePath = './SLBrecords.csv';

$fileArr = file( $filePath );

//$fileArr = file( $filePath, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($fileArr as $k=>$line) {
    if (strpos($line,$snum) !== false) {
        unset($fileArr[$k]);
        trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $fileArr[$k]));
    }
}
$success = FALSE;
if ( file_put_contents( $filePath, implode( '', $fileArr ), LOCK_EX ) )
{
    $success = TRUE;
}

header("Location: sfadhome.php");

?>
```

Comment: trim(preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $fileArr[$k])); try like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revision #5 meanwhile and I did a major test (with all kinds of strings - also "\n" and "\r\n") - I think this one is the one you are looking for:

```
<?php

 $cont = file_get_contents($filePath);

 $quoted = preg_quote($snum);

 $replace = array(
   '/^[^\r\n]*'.$quoted.'[^\r\n]*($|\r?\n)/' => '',
   '/\r?\n[^\r\n]*'.$quoted.'[^\r\n]*($|\r?\n)/' => '$1'
 );

 $cont = trim(preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $cont));

 file_put_contents($filePath, $cont);
```

Please tell me if it doesn't work - I'm sure we'll fix it!